# numpy arrays type conversion in C

Tags: python, numpy, swig

I would like to convert the numpy double array to numpy float array in C(Swig).
I am trying to use

```
PyObject *object = PyArray_FROM_OT(input,NPY_FLOAT)
```

or

```
PyObject *object = PyArray_FROMANY(input,NPY_FLOAT,0,0,NPY_DEFAULT)
```

or

```
PyObject *object = PyArray_FromObject(input,NPY_FLOAT,0,0)
```

or

```
PyObject *object = PyArray_ContiguousFromAny(input,NPY_FLOAT,0,0)
```

But all of them return NULL? Am I missing anything?

Comment: No answers yet? Can anyone tell me how to convert types using API in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is correct, yet your assumption about they numpy C API is not. NPY_FLOAT is just an integral constant, yet the functions you posted require the type parameter to be *a pointer to a [PyArray_Descr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#PyArray_Descr) struct*.

In order to get a type description from a mere type, you can call PyArray_DescrFromType, so your call could look like this:

```
PyArrayObject* float_array = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_FromAny(input,PyArray_DescrFromType(NPY_FLOAT64), 0,0, flags);
```

...with flags being whatever flags you deem meaningful when converting - please have a look at the numpy API, both for correct API invocation and for the meaning of different flags and values.